# Twilio Device Setup - Registers, Connects to TWiML App, but won't accept calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Am trying to setup a soft phone in browser, via TWiML app.

I created the following:

- A page on my own server which serves TWiML to dial a number, say '+11111111111'.
- A TWiML app which points to that page
- A Twilio number which points to that app.
- A page on my server which creates a Twilio Device associated with the app and buttons to run `device.connect()` or `device.register()`

The device is setup correctly, as I can register and connect with no errors.
The app works - the phone rings at +111 when I press "Call Using Twilio" button on the [TWiML app page](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/apps/), when I call the number pointing to the TWiML app, and when I press the button on my own page. Yay!

What I cannot figure out:

- How to answer the phone using the Twilio Device.
  *The device registers with no issue, so why doesn't it get incoming calls?*
- How to call other numbers aside from the one in my app.
  *I did in device.connect(`{params: {To: '+2222222222'}}`), why doesn't it call that number?*

Here are all the relevant pages:

calls.pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
      title Browser Calls
    body
      input#call(type="submit" value="call")
      input#register(type="submit" value="register")
      pre
      script(src="/js/twilio-sdk/twilio.js")
      script(type="module" src="/js/calls.js")
```

[client] calls.js

```js
const $ = css => document.querySelector(css);
const echo = msg => $('pre').innerText += msg + "\n";
    
var device;
    
async function setupDevice(){
    
    let data = await fetch('/token/new');
    data = await data.json();
    
    device = new Twilio.Device(data.token);
    device.on("error",
        err => echo("Twilio.Device Error: " + err.message));
    
    echo ('Device setup complete.')
    }
    
$('#register').addEventListener('click', async e => {
    if (!device) await setupDevice();
    
    device.on("registered", conn =>
        echo('Ready to accept incoming calls.')
        );
    device.on("incoming", call =>
        echo('Incoming call to device')
        );
    device.register()
    });
    
$('#call').addEventListener('click', async e => {
    if (!device) await setupDevice();
    let params = { To: '+22222222222' }
    device.connect({ params })
    });
```

[node] token.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
    
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VoiceGrant = AccessToken.VoiceGrant;
    
const config = require('../config');
router.get('/new', function (req, res) {
    const accessToken = new AccessToken(
        config.accountSid, config.apiKey, config.apiSecret, {identity: 'SG'}
        );
    
    const grant = new VoiceGrant({
    outgoingApplicationSid: config.appSid,
        incomingAllow: true,
        });
    accessToken.addGrant(grant);
    
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ token: accessToken.toJwt() }));
    });
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> - How to answer the phone using the Twilio Device.
>
>   The device registers with no issue, so why doesn't it get incoming calls?

To direct a call to the Device, you need to return TwiML that [`<Dial>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) the [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) with the ID of your access token ("SG" in this case).

So, if you want calls to your Twilio number to be directed to this client you should update the Twilio number's incoming webhook to point to a URL that returns this:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>
      <Identity>SG</Identity>
    </Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

> - How to call other numbers aside from the one in my app.
>   I did in device.connect({params: {To: '+2222222222'}}), why doesn't it call that number?

Currently, it sounds like you point the Device to a TwiML app that responds with static TwiML that dials your example number '+11111111111'. To use the parameters, you will need to make that TwiML dynamic, by returning it from your Node server instead. The parameters are sent to the TwiML endpoint, so you can then use them in the response.

Here is an example Express endpoint that would work for you:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { VoiceResponse } = require("twilio").twiml;
const config = require('../config');

router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post("/call", function(res, res) {
  const To = req.body;
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  const dial = twiml.dial({ callerId: config.twilioNumber });
  dial.number(To);
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Re: incoming - Just tried with`dial.client('SG')` as in the example at https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client. It worked, but without the `<Identity>` XML element, instead just doing `<Client>SG</<Client>`. Is `<Identity>` optional? Where are the docs for the node `dial()` method?

Comment: Using the identity element is optional, but allows for you to pass `<Parameter>`s too, if you need it. Docs for the dial method are here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.67.1/VoiceResponse.html